# How can I disable caching for directory listing?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

How can I get a **NEW (not cached)** file list each time?

I've got  a simple php script that puts the contents of a directory into an array.
It works great the FIRST time I use it but then when I call it again 8 minutes later it still provides the *previous* list of files. I know that **NEW** files are added to the directory every six or seven minutes and I need the newest files.
In my code snip you'll see I've tried various "no cache" suggestions but they do not work.

```
<?php 
//header(“Pragma: no-cache”);
//header(“cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate”); // HTTP/1.1
//header(“Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT”); // Date in the past

$mySite = ("http://mysite.com/mypath/mydirectory/");
$url = $radarSite;
$html = file_get_contents($url);
$count = preg_match_all('/<td><a href="([^"]+)">[^<]*<\/a><\/td>/i', $html, $files);

print json_encode($files[1]);

?>
```

Comment: is the remote server doing the caching perhaps?

Comment: Try using: `$radarSite = "http://radar.weather.gov/ridge/RadarImg/NCR/JAX/?_=" . time()`

Comment: re: "is the remote server doing the caching".. I would hope not. It's the government source for the the latest "sweep" of each NexRad display. It's used by the weather channel and everyone else that needs a "snapshot" of the most recent NexRad sweep. If their server is "caching" that would defeat the whole purpose of updating the directory every six minutes.

Comment: I've tried appending a rand to end (similar to the time idea) but then the script does not run...any other ideas?..is this a bug with file_get_contents?

Comment: update: "Try using: $radarSite = "http://radar.weather.gov/ridge/RadarImg/NCR/JAX/?_=" . time() – Ian yesterday" is correct. I made a typo in his suggestion and thought that it did not work; but it does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question: How can I get a NEW (not cached) file list each time?

"Ian" is correct.
This will "force" a new file list to be returned.

generically, it will look like this:

```
$mySite = ("http://mysite.com/mypath/mydirectory/?v=".time());
```